# Setting Smart DNS on 18.04

Tags: networking, dns

Have upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and can no longer install Smart DNS.
With the original install I lost all internet connections and the only way to resolve this was to reinstall 16.04.
Ithen set up 18.04 to boot from USB. Internet connection was fine but after a manual install of my Smart DNS values and rebooting they failed to work and the general settings still have 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 and I am geo blocked.
16.04 had no problem with installing my Smart DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works but is not a satisfactory.
Read a post that suggested I change the settings in my router.
This worked but I now have this on all my networked devices, which is not an ideal solution.

Comment: After setting DNS in router and going back to the network settings I noticed that the correct  DNS values are now listed in the general settings.